# Condição no VBA se Data informada no TextBox for Maior ou Menor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data

Estou com uma macro para caso a **Data** que o usuário inseriu no **TextBox**, for **menor** que a data de uma célula de determinada linha, eu farei uma alteração na informação de uma coluna desta linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Sub test()

Dim data As String
Dim ultima As Long
Dim split As Range

data = TextBox4.Value
data_i = Format(data, "dd/mm/yy")

ultima = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set split = Range("B7:B" & ultima)

For Each cell In split

    If cell < data_i Then
    
        cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Data Menor"
    
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Eu sei que o VBA lê em formato americano. Teria que transformar as datas da coluna B em "mm/dd/yy"  para fazer a comparação com o que o usurário escreveu no TextBox?

Qual seria a melhor maneira de resolver isso, por favor?

Agradeço desde já! Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo se seu Excel estiver configurado em inglês, não é preciso mudar a formatação da data na sua planilha. Eu já fiz comparações datas com padrão "brasileiro" em Excel configurado em inglês americano e funcionou.

Eu não sei como a planilha funciona como um todo, porém eu queria sugerir que:

- As variáveis de data fossem declaradas como "As Date"
- Ao invés de usar "TextBox" dentro de um formulário, eu usaria o método "inputbox", desse jeito:

```
data = InputBox("Qual a data que você gostaria de inserir?")
```

Assim, dá para manipular datas usando as devidas propriedades, diferentemente do que ocorre com *Strings* e comparar as datas no formato dia/mês/ano.

Além disso, o "cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Data Menor" está inserindo o texto "Data Menor" em cima dos valores da coluna "Preço Unitário". Eu não sei se onde esse texto deveria ser posicionado, mas creio que terá que mudar o índice usado para a coluna.

Espero que ajude.